# Export point size graduated

Tags: qgis, export

I would like to export from QGIS to another map (eg umap, openstreetmap) in kml or other format of the graduated points with different measures based on the concentration of certain events. Unfortunately, exporting them to any format I find only the markers on the destination map. Do you know how I can solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graduation is a style choice, not a data property, so it does not get exported. I'm pretty sure you'll have to recreate it in the target system, but you can give some of the export plugins (eg. to leaflet) a try and check if they recreate the style for you.